# Unable to sort event participants by participant name after search?

Tags: civievent, search

It seems it's not possible to sort event participants by name after the search. To reproduce:

- Go to events, find participants,
- Select an event under event name,
- Select participant status (example registered),
- Hit the search button.
- The expected results are displayed,
- now click on the Participant column of the search results to sort alphabetically by name
- now you get 'No matches found' for our search criteria.
- Hit the search button again.

Now the results are redisplayed with this warning message:

```
Warning: array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer in CRM_Utils_Array::value() (line 55 of /srv/buildkit/build/d46/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Array.php).
Notice: Array to string conversion in CRM_Contact_BAO_Query::buildQillForFieldValue() (line 5753 of /srv/buildkit/build/d46/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php).
```

The version of CiviCRM Version is 4.6.24.

It seems this un-expected behaviour only happens when searching for events participants and Participant status is selected.

Comment: I just reproduced this situation on http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/ . Sorting on other fields (for example fee lever) has the same result.

Comment: Can you take a look in JIRA and see if anyone has reported this bug, otherwise it might need adding.